# How to use onclick in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick

I need to know how to use `onclick` so that it allows me to reuse the `onclick` method of a `div` over and over again and not have to add an infinite amount of them.
  I don't want to have to do this:

```
<div id="div1" onClick="divFunction1()">
</div>
<div id="div2" onClick="divFunction2()">
</div>
<div id="div3" onClick="divFunction3()">
</div>
<div id="div4" onClick="divFunction4()">
</div>
```

But instead do something like this in JavaScript if possible:

```
div = document.getElementById("allPurposeDiv").onclick...
```

I'm not exactly sure what would come after onclick is the problem.

Any help is appriciated, Thanks!

Comment: `document.getElementById("div1").onclick = whatever;`

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you want to do, but maybe having a look at this might help: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onclick` is case sensitive. So it is `onclick`. It expects a callback function to be assigned to it, which will be called.

```
document.getElementById("div1").onclick = divFunction;
```

If you are trying to add more events, then you need a event listener like what adeneo has suggested.

Comment: Thanks so much! This helped a lot and I have been having a hard time with it. :P I am not real good at programming anyway so i appriciate the help!

Comment: @Geroy290, glad to have helped

Answer (score 0):

You should generally use `addEventListener` for that

```
document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('click', function() {

    alert('clicked the DIV');

}, false);
```

or to reference a named function

```
function divFunction() {
    alert('clicked the DIV');
}

document.getElementById('div1').addEventListener('click', divFunction, false);
```

I have no idea why this would help you not add an infinite amount of elements ?